# STM32 "Blue Pill" Serial.print freezes Serial Monitor

Tags: arduino-ide

I am having difficulties when printing any type of variable using the Serial.print(ln) command.

The Serial Monitor becomes inactive after printing for approximately 7 - 15 times.

I currently have the STM32 Blue Pill Board, running Mac OS Mojave and Arduino IDE v 1.8.9

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(PC13, OUTPUT);

}

void loop() {
  float raw = analogRead(PA0);
  float voltage = (raw * 3.3) / 4096;
  Serial.println(voltage);
  delay(500);
}
```

Comment: isolate the area of the error .... start by changing the print command to `Serial.println("voltage");` .... it will print the word "voltage" .... just let it run to see if it also hangs up

Answer (score 1):

Have you made sure to modify the board before using it?

[This page](https://stm32duinoforum.com/forum/wiki_subdomain/index_title_Blue_Pill.html) mentions at least one resistor that you have to replace for the USB to "work".

> The USB standard requires a 1.5 kΩ pullup resistor on D+, but this board is known to have a wrong value (R10 on the board). It ships with either a 10 kΩ resistor or a 4.7 kΩ resistor, but it should be replaced with a 1.5 kΩ resistor, or put an appropriate resistor value (e.g 1.8 kΩ) in between PA12 and 3.3V.
>
> It is also true that some PCs are tolerant of incorrect value so, before you change the resistance, you can try if it works in your case.

I have had issues with bluepill boards myself in the past, but never had an issue like yours after fixing the resistor. (before that, I couldn't even flash the bootloader)

Try printing other things with the board, and see if there's any pattern to it cutting out. e.g. a string over and over again, or the same float over and over again.

Try different baudrates, or even SoftwareSerial to another board.

Answer (score 0):

Printing a float should work (at least with an Arduino), but to test if it cannot handle it correctly, I suggest you convert the float to a string (e.g., with the `C` function `ftoa`, and print the characters one by one or as a string.

Since this C function is not available on Arduino, use the function implementation of [this article](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=63721.0), credits to Martin Waller:

```
char *ftoa(char *buffer, double d, int precision) {

    long wholePart = (long) d;

    // Deposit the whole part of the number.

    itoa(wholePart,buffer,10);

    // Now work on the faction if we need one.

    if (precision > 0) {

        // We do, so locate the end of the string and insert
        // a decimal point.

        char *endOfString = buffer;
        while (*endOfString != '\0') endOfString++;
        *endOfString++ = '.';

        // Now work on the fraction, be sure to turn any negative
        // values positive.

        if (d < 0) {
            d *= -1;
            wholePart *= -1;
        }

        double fraction = d - wholePart;
        while (precision > 0) {

            // Multipleby ten and pull out the digit.

            fraction *= 10;
            wholePart = (long) fraction;
            *endOfString++ = '0' + wholePart;

            // Update the fraction and move on to the
            // next digit.

            fraction -= wholePart;
            precision--;
        }

        // Terminate the string.

        *endOfString = '\0';
    }

   return buffer;
}
```